# I always get the wrong response to the FIRST query result (it happens everytime i change my query)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, serverside-javascript, nodejs-server

i am doing server side programming using nodejs native.
I wrote my code on server.js as given below:

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();//initialized app as an express app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

let newConfirmed = null;
let requestedCountryCode = null;

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    let selectedCountry = req.body.searchInput;//used body-parser here
    ltBraceIndex = selectedCountry.indexOf('(');
    requestedCountryCode = selectedCountry.slice(ltBraceIndex+1, ltBraceIndex+3)//generating value of the requestedCountryCode variable

    //Get Covid details
    const covidUrl = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary"
    https.get(covidUrl, (response) => {    
        
        let chunks = [];
        response
            .on('data', (chunk)=>{
                chunks.push(chunk);
            })
            .on('end', ()=>{
                let data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                let covidData = JSON.parse(data); 
                covidData.Countries.forEach(Object => {
                    if(Object.CountryCode === requestedCountryCode){
                        newConfirmed = Object.NewConfirmed;
                    }
                });
            })
            .on("error", (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        
        console.log(newConfirmed);    
    })
});
```

I have illustrated my issue below in the attached images. (see VS Code terminal)

1.img1: I entered afghanistan in the search bar.

[image]

2. img2: I entered India in the search bar.
   [image]

Why is this happening? Please help me with this issue. I always get the response to the first query result wrong (as shown in the terminal in the images above) everytime i change my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first request gives you `null` in the log because you declare `newConfirmed` as such.

```
let newConfirmed = null
```

Now, why it is using the value when you already request from an API?, you might ask.

It is because you put `console.log()` outside the `end` event of the response.

```
   response
        .on('data', (chunk)=>{
            chunks.push(chunk);
        })
        .on('end', ()=>{
            let data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            let covidData = JSON.parse(data); 
            covidData.Countries.forEach(Object => {
                if(Object.CountryCode === requestedCountryCode){
                    newConfirmed = Object.NewConfirmed;
                }
            });
        })
        .on("error", (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
  
    console.log(newConfirmed);
```

This makes the script execute `console.log()` before the event `end` gets fired hence the old value.

What you need to do to change this is to put the `console.log()` inside the `end` event so that it will log when the data is really ready.

```
   response
        .on('data', (chunk)=>{
            chunks.push(chunk);
        })
        .on('end', ()=>{
            let data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            let covidData = JSON.parse(data); 
            covidData.Countries.forEach(Object => {
                if(Object.CountryCode === requestedCountryCode){
                    newConfirmed = Object.NewConfirmed;
                    console.log(newConfirmed);
                }
            });
        })
        .on("error", (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Comment: I know this is a dumb question...but still i want to know this....is response.on() occuring asynchronously? I searched mdn but i cant find anything mentioning this fact

Comment: @AshutoshKhandual Yes. When any specified event occurs, it will execute the callback function. So, it is indeed asynchronous since the program will execute response.on() and go on without waiting for events to have a response first.